# How to represent very small floating point numbers in fixed point ( 32 bits )?

Tags: floating-point, precision, fixed-point

I have a floating point code, in which some variables have range = 1.0e-12 to 7.89e-20 ( very very small floating point number ).

I need to convert the floating point code to 32-bit fixed point. How can I fix the Q format for these variables?

Obviously, if I convert these values in 32 bit fixed point, it will be zero.

```
(int)(1.0e-12 x 2^31) = 0 in Q1.31
```

Also multiplication, addition is performed on these variables.

My code deals with very low end amplitude signals, that is why the variable range is so small.

### Is there any way to represent very small values like above in 32-bit fixed point?

I don't have the exact source of information, but somewhere I read that, to represent smaller floating point number use pseudo-floating point in integer format.

Like, in 32-bit integer variable : take 8 bits to represent exponent and 24 bits to represent mantissa.

```
(int)(1.0e-12 x 2^31 x 2^25) = 72057 in Q1.31

exponent = 25 and mantissa = 72057
packing this inside 32-bit integer = 0x19011979
First 8 bits = 0x19 = 25
Rest 24 bits = 0x011979 = 72057
```

Will the above method resolve my issue? How will I do multiplication or addition in this packed number?

Comment: You can construct a scaled fixed-point format: Multiply each number by 2^64 (for example), round to the nearest integer, and use that. To give the best precision, make the scale as large as possible without causing any number you work with to exceed 32-bit integers. Addition and subtraction is simply ordinary integer addition or subtraction. Multiplication is not feasible within the range you give as the product of any two numbers in the range is outside the range (1e-12•1e-12 = 1e-24). You would have to adjust the scale.

Comment: For numbers within a range closer to 1, multiplication of scaled values is possible by adjusting for the scale. For example, if we have integers x and y scaled by q, so they actually represent numbers x/q and y/q, then multiplication is performed by calculating x•y/q, since x•y/q represents x•y/q/q which is the product of the represented numbers x/q and y/q.

Comment: The scheme you mention of using pseudo-floating-point in integer format is not pseudo-floating-point; it is floating-point. Sometimes it is called software floating-point to indicate it is implemented in software instead of hardware. In that case, you should prefer to use a standard floating-point format and search for information on implementing software floating-point.